# Incorrect output- Why?

Tags: java

Write a method named randomWalk that performs a random one-dimensional walk, reporting each position reached and the maximum position reached during the walk. The random walk should begin at position 0. On each step, you should either increase or decrease the position by 1 (with equal probability). The walk stops when 3 or -3 is hit. The output should look like this:

```
position = 0
position = 1
position = 0
position = -1
position = -2
position = -1
position = -2
position = -3
max position = 1
```

My code:

```
public static void randomWalk() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int position = 0;
    int max = 0;
    System.out.println("position = " + position);
    while (position != 3 && position != -3) {
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(2) * 2 - 1;
        position = position - randomNumber; //why the minus?
        max = Math.max(max , position);
        System.out.println("position = " + position);
    }
    System.out.println("max position = " + max);
}
```

I initially had the plus sign instead of the minus sign, and 3 out 4 outputs were incorrect (image attached). Is it something to do with the output console or is my code somewhere wrong?
[image: With minus sign]

[image: With plus sign]

Comment: A + would do equally well there... it's not clear how they expect a particular output when you're using random numbers. But you haven't shown us the *end* of that output - maybe it's really just checking the max position?

Comment: while i think your question is pretty complete i don´t get what is wrong with the code? It does decrease by one or increase by one by judging the ouput, so whats wrong there?

Comment: @KevinEsche Exactly my problem there, it should work well with the + sign but still the output is wrong. I don't know how they check the output as it's dealing with random numbers though.

Comment: @TheBolt well in my eyes it doesn´t really make sense to have an expected output when the value you use to increase/decrease is random. (why should it start with -1?)

Comment: Yeah makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I initially had the plus sign instead of the minus sign, and 3 out 4 outputs were incorrect (image attached). Is it something to do with the output console or is my code somewhere wrong?

It was *not* "incorrect", *given the requirements that we know of*. The `max` variable tracks the maximum value that was reached. It's inevitably a positive number. The highest positive number reached was 1 before reaching the -3 exit condition.

Your implementation works equally well regardless of plus or minus `randomNumber`. Just the direction of the walks will be flipped, that's all. You can observe this easily by initializing the `Random` instance with a seed, for example `new Random(1)`, and then try a run with plus and minus. One of them will reach 3 and the other -3, taking opposite directions at every step.

On a second read I see now that you're probably running the program through some kind of judge system, and by "incorrect", you mean the printed values are opposites of what's expected by this judge. Changing the plus minus sign fixes that, for the reason I explained above. Whichever sign you use, I don't think your program is incorrect. The hidden requirement to use a specific sign is unreasonable and unnatural, as whether you plus or minus is irrelevant in terms of the principle of random walks.